# How many ways are there to arrange 10 distinct tasks of type A and 10 distinct tasks of type B in 7 slots?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Restrictions:**

- No 2 tasks of type B can be adjacent in the arrangement.
- Same task can occur multiple times in the arrangement.
- One slot can have one task.
- No slot can be empty

Also, What would happen if the number of slots is greater than the number of Task A + number of Task B?

**Edit 1:**

Similar Question: [How many ways are there to arrange 10 distinct men and 10 distinct women on 7 seats, such that no 2 women are together?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510380/how-many-ways-are-there-to-arrange-10-distinct-men-and-10-distinct-women-on-7-se)

The question is different from this one in the sense that a tasks can be performed/placed in slot twice but a man/woman cannot sit on two seats.

Comment: What does "placed together" mean?  do you mean "in the same slot"?  But of course you have to have at least one slot with more than one $B$.

Comment: "placed together" means adjacent slots, one task per slot

Comment: That is a very odd interpretation of "placed together".  I don't think your readers will guess at that.

Comment: @lulu updated the ques to change it to "adjacent"

Comment: @Arthur The question is different in the sense that a tasks can be performed/placed in slot twice but a man/woman cannot sit on two seats. Or can he/she?

Comment: This is NOT DUPLICATE men/women cannot be repeated but tasks can.

Comment: Why would I myself ask same ques twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*HINT*

To meet the non-adjacency clause, there can be at most $4$ tasks of type $B,\;viz\; BABABAB$
[Available spots for $B = (\#\; of\; A \;tasks\;+1)$, slots numbered *after* placing $Bs$ ]

Suppose there are two of $B$, thus five of $A$, since **each** task is distinct, choose the tasks in $\binom{10}{2}\binom{10}5$ ways, and place the $Bs$ in $\binom62 = 15$ ways in the slots. Finally,  permute  in $2!5!$ ways.

Work out similarly for number of $B$ tasks from $0\;through\;4$ and add up.

---

If the same task can be repeated any number of times, it is equivalent to finding the number of distinct words that can be formed with an alphabet of $ABCDEFGHIJabcdefghij$ in $n$ slots, with $k$ non-adjacent small letters, $ k \le (n-k+1)$

Ignoring the non-adjacency clause,
 # of distinct words = coefficient of $x^n$ in $(n!)(1+ x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + .... \frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!})^{10}(1+ x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + .... \frac{x^k}{k!})^{10}$

For an explanation of the formula, see  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509722/how-many-different-unique-4-letter-arrangements-are-there-of-the-letters-in-th/2511768#2511768)

P(small letters are non-adjacent)$ = \frac{\binom{n-k+1}{k}}{\binom {n}{k}}$

Multiply the two expresssions, and sum up for $k = 0 \; through\; (n-k+1)$

Comment: "Same task can occur multiple times in the arrangement". So some tasks will repeat, then no slot will be empty.

Comment: I have added a generalized answer that takes care of the above.

Comment: Re your **Edit 1**, it is the same as the first part of the original question.